# How can I backup a phone running Windows Phone 7?

Tags: sync, phone

Really the important bit is how can I backup the contacts. Everything else can be transferred to a SD card.

Background:

A friend get a present last Christmas, a Nokia Lumia 900, a phone running Windows Phone. Now it's faulty and he has to return it for exchange. The support person told him that he should make a backup using Zune, but he only has a very old computer running Lubuntu (it has less than 400 Mb of RAM, virtualized Windows won't run on that hardware).

For now I can just sync it in my laptop (powerful enough for VirtualBox), but I'd like to have some alternative for the future so that he can make a backup himself.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows Phone, you can sync your contacts with the cloud (Windows Live can syncs contacts). If you don't like Windows Live you can sync them on a google Account.
I'm using that kind of services with my Windows Phone.